# Fully convolutional neural network producing all zeros in segmentation task

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I am using tensorflow to train a fully convolutional neural network for region of interest segmentation in MRI data with ground-truth masks. I am ideally hoping for it to produce a "probability map" of the ROI in the same shape as the input it is provided.

My network is running without error, but when I load my weights and run a prediction, I am left with an array of all zeros. I am hoping someone can help me figure out why.

My network takes one 96x80 MRI slice along with a "flipped" version of it together as one batch.

My network is defined as such, in summary, it uses series of convolutions and maxpooling to obtain highly sampled feature maps, it then uses a series of transposed convolutions to upsample these maps into a segmentation. In particular, I sum together upsampled versions of the maxpool operations in the final step:

```
def maxpool2dWrap(x, k=2):
# MaxPool2D wrapper
    return tf.nn.max_pool(x, ksize=[1, k, k, 1], strides=[1, k, k, 1], padding='SAME')


def conv2dWrap(x, W, b, strides=1):
    # Conv2D wrapper, with bias and relu activation
    x = tf.nn.conv2d(x, W, strides=[1, strides, strides, 1], padding='SAME', data_format='NHWC')
    x = tf.nn.bias_add(x, b)
    return tf.nn.relu(x)

def conv2dTransWrap(x, W, b, shape, strides=[1,2,2,2]):
    dyn_input_shape = tf.shape(x)
    batch_size = dyn_input_shape[0]
    x = tf.nn.conv2d_transpose(x, W, [batch_size,shape[0],shape[1],shape[2]], strides, padding='SAME')
    x = tf.nn.bias_add(x,b)
    return tf.nn.relu(x)

def conv_net(x, weights, biases):    
    conv1   = conv2dWrap(x,     weights['wConv1'], biases['bConv1'])
    conv2   = conv2dWrap(conv1, weights['wConv2'], biases['bConv2'])
    conv2   = maxpool2dWrap(conv2)

    conv3   = conv2dWrap(conv2, weights['wConv3'], biases['bConv3'])
    conv4   = conv2dWrap(conv3, weights['wConv4'], biases['bConv4'])
    conv4   = maxpool2dWrap(conv4)

    conv5   = conv2dWrap(conv4, weights['wConv5'], biases['bConv5'])
    conv6   = conv2dWrap(conv5, weights['wConv6'], biases['bConv6'])
    conv6   = maxpool2dWrap(conv6)

    conv7   = conv2dWrap(conv6, weights['wConv7'], biases['bConv7'])
    conv8   = conv2dWrap(conv7, weights['wConv8'], biases['bConv8'])
    conv8   = maxpool2dWrap(conv8)

    conv9   = conv2dWrap(conv8, weights['wConv9'], biases['bConv9'])
    conv10  = conv2dWrap(conv9, weights['wConv10'], biases['bConv10'])
    conv11  = conv2dWrap(conv10, weights['wConv11'], biases['bConv11'])
    conv12  = conv2dWrap(conv11, weights['wConv12'], biases['bConv12'])

    conv13  = conv2dTransWrap(conv12, weights['wConv13'], biases['bConv13'],[10,12,256],[1,2,2,1])
    conv14  = conv2dWrap(conv13, weights['wConv14'], biases['bConv14'])
    conv15  = conv2dWrap(conv14, weights['wConv15'], biases['bConv15'])

    conv16  = conv2dTransWrap(conv15, weights['wConv16'], biases['bConv16'],[20,24,128],[1,2,2,1])
    conv17  = conv2dWrap(conv16, weights['wConv17'], biases['bConv17'])
    conv18  = conv2dWrap(conv17, weights['wConv18'], biases['bConv18'])

    conv19  = conv2dTransWrap(conv18, weights['wConv19'], biases['bConv19'],[40,48,64],[1,2,2,1])
    conv20  = conv2dWrap(conv19, weights['wConv20'], biases['bConv20'])
    conv21  = conv2dWrap(conv20, weights['wConv21'], biases['bConv21'])

    conv22  = conv2dTransWrap(conv21, weights['wConv22'], biases['bConv22'],[80,96,32],[1,2,2,1])
    conv23  = conv2dWrap(conv22, weights['wConv23'], biases['bConv23'])
    conv24  = conv2dWrap(conv23, weights['wConv24'], biases['bConv24']) 


    #SKIP CONNECTIONS
    conv25  = conv2dTransWrap(conv4, weights['wConv25'], biases['bConv25'],[80,96,16],[1,4,4,1])
    conv26  = conv2dTransWrap(conv6, weights['wConv26'], biases['bConv26'],[80,96,16],[1,8,8,1])
    conv27  = conv2dTransWrap(conv8, weights['wConv27'], biases['bConv27'],[80,96,16],[1,16,16,1])

    features = conv24+conv25+conv26+conv27

    convOUT = conv2dWrap(features, weights['wOUT'], biases['bOUT'])

    convOUT = tf.reshape(convOUT, [-1])
    print(convOUT.shape)
    return convOUT
```

My weights and biases are initialized thusly:

```
weights = {
# 3x3 conv, 1 input, 3 outputs
'wConv1':  tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3, 3, 1,  16],0,.01),  name='wConv1'),
'wConv2':  tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3, 3, 16, 16],0,.004),  name='wConv2'),
'wConv3':  tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3, 3, 16, 32],0,.004),  name='wConv3'),
'wConv4':  tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3, 3, 32, 32],0,.002), name='wConv4'),
'wConv5':  tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3, 3, 32, 64],0,.002), name='wConv5'),
'wConv6':  tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3, 3, 64, 64],0,.002),  name='wConv6'),
'wConv7':  tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3, 3, 64, 128],0,.001),  name='wConv7'),
'wConv8':  tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3, 3, 128, 128],0,.001),  name='wConv8'),
'wConv9':  tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3, 3, 128, 256],0,.001),  name='wConv9'),
'wConv10':  tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3, 3, 256, 256],0,.001),  name='wConv10'),
'wConv11':  tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3, 3, 256, 512],0,.001),  name='wConv11'),
'wConv12':  tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3, 3, 512, 512],0,.0007),  name='wConv12'),
'wConv13':  tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3, 3, 256, 512],0,.0007),  name='wConv13'),
'wConv14':  tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3, 3, 256, 256],0,.001),  name='wConv14'),
'wConv15':  tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3, 3, 256, 256],0,.001),  name='wConv15'),
'wConv16':  tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3, 3, 128, 256],0,.001),  name='wConv16'),
'wConv17':  tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3, 3, 128, 128],0,.001),  name='wConv17'),
'wConv18':  tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3, 3, 128, 128],0,.001),  name='wConv18'),
'wConv19':  tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3, 3, 64, 128],0,.001),  name='wConv19'),
'wConv20':  tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3, 3, 64, 64],.002),  name='wConv20'),
'wConv21':  tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3, 3, 64, 64],0,.002),  name='wConv21'),
'wConv22':  tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3, 3, 32, 64],0,.002),  name='wConv22'),
'wConv23':  tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3, 3, 32, 32],0,.002),  name='wConv23'),
'wConv24':  tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3, 3, 32, 16],0,.002),  name='wConv24'),
'wConv25':  tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3, 3, 16, 32],0,.004),  name='wConv25'),
'wConv26':  tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3, 3, 16, 64],0,.002),  name='wConv26'),
'wConv27':  tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3, 3, 16, 128],0,.001),  name='wConv27'),

'wOUT'  :  tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3, 3, 16, 1],0,.01),   name='wOUT')
}

biases = {
'bConv1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([16],0,.01),   name='bConv1'),
'bConv2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([16],0,.01),  name='bConv2'),
'bConv3': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([32],0,.01),  name='bConv3'),
'bConv4': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([32],0,.01), name='bConv4'),
'bConv5': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([64],0,.01),  name='bConv5'),
'bConv6': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([64],0,.01),  name='bConv6'),
'bConv7': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([128],0,.01),  name='bConv7'),
'bConv8': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([128],0,.01),  name='bConv8'),
'bConv9': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([256],0,.01),  name='bConv9'),
'bConv10': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([256],0,.01),  name='bConv10'),
'bConv11': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([512],0,.01),  name='bConv11'),
'bConv12': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([512],0,.01),  name='bConv12'),
'bConv13': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([256],0,.01),  name='bConv13'),
'bConv14': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([256],0,.01),  name='bConv14'),
'bConv15': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([256],0,.01),  name='bConv15'),
'bConv16': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([128],0,.01),  name='bConv16'),
'bConv17': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([128],0,.01),  name='bConv17'),
'bConv18': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([128],0,.01),  name='bConv18'),
'bConv19': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([64],0,.01),  name='bConv19'),
'bConv20': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([64],0,.01),  name='bConv20'),
'bConv21': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([64],0,.01),  name='bConv21'),
'bConv22': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([32],0,.01),  name='bConv22'),
'bConv23': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([32],0,.01),  name='bConv23'),
'bConv24': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([16],0,.01),  name='bConv24'),
'bConv25': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([16],0,.01),  name='bConv25'),
'bConv26': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([16],0,.01),  name='bConv26'),
'bConv27': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([16],0,.01),  name='bConv27'),
'bOUT': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1],0,.01),     name='bOUT')
}
```

I am using Adams optimizer and tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy as my loss function.

Comment: Is it the same when you test it in the training session?

Comment: Yes, although the output will occasionally be a homogenous array of values between -1^-3 and 1^-3. I'm occasionally pulling the weights off of the server I'm training on and running predictions locally.

Comment: What makes you think that it has learned? Can you post your training accuracy?